# Check if url has given words Jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, indexof

I have in some url that i have to performe some Jquery function, but by time url will be added, now i have something like this,

```
var loc = window.location.pathname; 
var pageOne = 'Project/Node';

if(loc.indexOf(pageOne) >= 0) { 
 // Do something
}
```

The problem is that pageOne, later i will have so many pages vars, and i want to add all that values in array something like this

```
// A simple array with constructor.
var myArray = new Array( "Project/Node", "Settings/" );
```

And then to check if url contains any word from array and do something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then do like this,

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;
var myArray = new Array( "Project/Node", "Settings/" );
var isFound = false; 

for(var i=0,len=myArray.length;i<len;i++) {
  if(loc.indexOf(myArray[i])> -1) {
     isFound = true;
     break;
  }
}    

if(isFound) { 
 // Do something
}
```

Comment: Why to check pageOne?? I need to check if url has word from array?

Comment: @Schneider Can you please open up your mouth regarding whether you got any solutions or not.?

Answer (score 0):

use **[inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)** in jquery  , it will return index if searched element is there ,if it is not it will return -1,

```
var myArray = new Array( "Project/Node", "Settings/" );

if($.inArray("Project/Node",myArray )> -1){
}
```

Comment: Ok, but i need to check url too?

Comment: Up voter think twice before you cast a vote. read the question carefully and have a look at my answer. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - your answer deleted

Comment: @Schneider - where is the url?

Comment: @Sudharsan in var loc!